# Laravel Android authentication

Tags: java, php, android, laravel-5

Is there any way to make an authentication system in laravel for both android and Web apps. 
Since android apps doesn't have sessions it is hard for me to figure another way to make an authentication with laravel

Answer (score 1):

Make login API for that .APIs **use access tokens to authenticate users** and they do not have session . 
You can use **laravel passport** for that which help you to maintain **Oauth2 server** for your application. So it is basically like sending login request via api and get the **access token** as a callback which will be used through out your android and web app.

see below

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-how-to-create-api-authentication-using-passport-example.html

Comment: Then how do I pass the csrf token?

Comment: you can disable csrf token